# How to emit filtered out error if flux is empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have synchronous code that I want to make non-blocking with reactor.

I want to call in parallel different URI, the calls can return a response, an error or nothing.

There are 3 cases:

- A request returns a response, I return it without waiting for the other requests to complete.
  If other requests returned errors earlier, I drop the errors
- At least one request returned an error and no other requests returned a response, I return an error
- All requests returned nothing (no response, no error), I return nothing

I already did this in a synchronous manner :

```
    AtomicReference<WebClientResponseException> responseException = new AtomicReference<>();
    
    String responseBody = Flux.fromIterable(uriList)
            .flatMap(url -> repo.sendRequest(uri)) 
            // sendRequest  returns a Mono that either emit a response, an error or nothing
            .onErrorContinue(WebClientResponseException.class, (error, element) -> {
                var webclientError = (WebClientResponseException) error;
                responseException.set(webclientError);
            })
            .blockFirst();
    
    return Pair.of(responseBody, responseException.get());
```

I want to remove the blocking call and return a Mono

From what I understand, I'm kind of keeping a state with the error that happened and I can't have a state with reactor.

How can I keep track of errors that happened but not emit them as I want to see if other request emit result later ?

Does this version works ?

```
AtomicReference<WebClientResponseException> responseException = new AtomicReference<>();
    
    return Flux.fromIterable(uriList)
            .flatMap(url -> repo.sendRequest(uri)) 
            // sendRequest  returns a Mono that either emit a response, an error or nothing
            .onErrorContinue(WebClientResponseException.class, (error, element) -> {
                var webclientError = (WebClientResponseException) error;
                responseException.set(webclientError);
            })
            .next()
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> Mono.error(responseException.get())));
```

Will the AtomicReference be closed over like a closure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `flatMapDelayError` may achieve what you are looking for, see this example:

```java
int concurrency = 10;
int prefetch = 1;

Flux.just(
        Mono.error(new IOException("error")).delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(2)),
        Mono.just("fast").delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(4)),
        Mono.just("slow").delaySubscription(Duration.ofSeconds(6)))
    .flatMapDelayError(
        request -> request,
        concurrency,
        prefetch)
    .next()
    .doOnNext(result -> System.out.println("Result: " + result))
```

In this example the `error` completes first, but the `-DelayError` operator holds it, then `fast` completes and is emitted as the result. Finally `slow` never completes, due to `.next()` canceling the remaining requests because we have a result.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick. I did not know this operator.
So the doc is not really clear but it seems that it emits a `CompositeException`if multiple errors are emitted.
If I want to retrieve one of the original error, does this seems correct : 
`.onErrorMap(RuntimeException.class, e -> Exceptions.unwrapMultiple(e).get(0))`
Also is there any reason you picked 10 and 1 as concurrency and prefetch and not the default value ?

Comment: Yes, if there are multiple errors then they will get bundled into a `CompositeException`, unwrapping it to retrieve them should be fine. About the `concurrency`, I used `10` as an example, but it should be adjusted depending on how many requests should be handled in parallel. About the `prefetch`, if I understand correctly it doesn't matter in this case because the inner elements are `Mono`, so there would only be 1 element anyway.